# Legalities of using song names in a music guessing trivia game

Tags: copyright, music

I have an idea for a new new music trivia game with a table top skirmish twist. My question is related to the trivia part of the game: are there any copyright laws against me using names of songs in my trivia questions?

The way the game works is that questions will be based on different genres of music (E.G. pop, hip hop, RnB, heavy metal, etc.) and players will be asked to describe it and have other players guess its name without saying the song name, but by quoting a lyric, humming the melody/harmony or base line.  Much like in the game [Articulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulate!), but you'd be describing music rather than people and things and there would be song names on the question cards for each category.

Am I able to do from a legal point of view or not.

Comment: This sounds like a question for a lawyer, not for a game developer. We can help you with how to make the *game* parts of your game — the code, the graphics, the game design of the mechanics, etc. because the same principles apply across many different games. For this question though, unless a user had made exactly this specific trivia game before (and consulted with a lawyer), they wouldn't have first-hand knowledge to share with you about whether your specific idea is legal. A lawyer can answer questions about legality though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this falls under fair use, but not positive

Comment: Ok, I suggest you google about copyright laws regarding trivia questions, because there are a ton of good results (some from real world lawyers) that can help, probably better than I can since I am not a lawyer  =)  Good luck on your project!  (Also, the general incentive I got from reading was that it is fair use, but I suggest you read for yourself)